# Magento 2.2.6: How to add <div> on product listing page without override file?

Tags: layout, frontend, magento2.2.6

I want to add custom div on product listing page under `class="product-image-container"` `<span>` without override `product list.phtml` & `catalog_category_view.xml` file.

And i also want to display dynamic data in to my custom div from database is it possible? if yes then how can i achieve this thing. for more reference check below screen-shoot.

[image]

Any help would be Appreciated!

Comment: you can add the data by using only refrence is available on list page. But your requirement is to add between, then you need to overide the file.

Comment: There is no any other way without override file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **di.xml** file at `/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` :

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="block-product-list" type="Vender\Module\Plugin\ProductList"/>
</type>
```

Create Plugin file **ProductList.php** at `/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin` :

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Plugin;

class ProductList
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $layout;   
    public function __construct(
        ...............
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        ...............
    ) {
        ...............
        $this->layout = $layout;
        ...............
    }
    public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        return $this->layout->createBlock('VendorName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName')->setTemplate('VendorName_ModuleName::yourphtml.phtml')->toHtml();
        /*If you want to specific product pass then you need to call phtml like 
        $this->layout->createBlock('VendorName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('VendorName_ModuleName::yourphtml.phtml')->toHtml();
        */
    }               
}
```

Hope, It may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, where i call phtml file because i want to add `<div>` inside this `class="product-image-container"` div as i mentioned in my post. +1 for your help :)

Comment: You need to inject class for layout and then call phtml file. See my updated answer.

Comment: Tnxs man it's work!, but position of my custom div is not as per my screen-shoot. can you explain how can i add this inside `class="product-image-container"`

Comment: please try to use aroundGetImage() function. It may be work.

Comment: Is it working or you can get reference from here vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php

Comment: using `aroundGetImage()` function?

Comment: Yes. Did you try it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85180/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-rohan-hapani).