# Magento 2 How I can add a div inside `product-image-container` in Magento to catalog pages

Tags: magento2, template, magento2.3.4, template-override

I want to add a New `<div>` in inside `class="product-image-container"` in Magento 2 I have searched and found that this class is rendered like this

```
$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
<?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
```

How I can do this task please let me know thank you

Comment: you want to add div in .phtml file ??

Comment: yes i want to add this div in this container but I cannot see it in any phtml file

Comment: which file added you div??

Comment: you refer this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248596/magento-2-2-6-how-to-add-div-on-product-listing-page-without-override-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can archive this by overridden the below file,

> **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml**

To your theme

> **app/design/frontend/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml**

In this file, you can add the custom class inside the

```
<span class="product-image-container" style="width:<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getWidth() ?>px;">
```

Save the file and clear cache, Hope this will work for you.

Comment: can i do this is custom module?

Comment: Yes, You can, Which Magento version you using?

Comment: i am using 2.3.4

Comment: This image template file called in "create" function of  "vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php" file. You can create the template file in your module and need to override this function in your module to set the custom template.

Comment: Ohh I got this thank you so much for Heo